# Question regarding the limit of $f(x)= \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$ using the MVT

Tags: calculus, mean-value-theorem

I need help understanding the mean value theorem.

Let $f:\mathbb{R^+} \cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)= \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$

We use $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Per the MVT, there exists $\xi \in (x,x+1)$:

$$g'(\xi) = \frac{g(x+1)-g(x)}{x+1-x} = \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \stackrel{!}{=} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}} \to 0 \text{ for } x \to \infty $$

since $x < \xi < x+1$.

What I don't understand are the following points:

$1.$ How do we get to $\frac{g(x+1)-g(x)}{x+1-x}$?

$2.$ How does that lead to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}}$?

According to Wikipedia the general formula is $\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

I think this formula was used for $\frac{g(x+1)-g(x)}{x+1-x}$, but how do we get to $h$?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>0$, then $g(x)=\sqrt x$ is continuous in $[x,x+1]$ and differentiable in $(x,x+1)$ So from the mean value theorem we have that there is $\xi$ in $(\color{red}{x},\color{blue}{x+1})$ sucha that
$$
g'(\xi)=\frac{\color{blue}{g(x+1)}-\color{red}{g(x)}}{\color{blue}{(x+1)}-\color{red}{x}}=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x\Rightarrow f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x=g'(\xi)
$$
On the other hand we have to:
$$
g(x)=\sqrt x\Rightarrow g'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}\Rightarrow g'(\xi)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt \xi}
$$
Therefore there is $\xi\in (x,x+1)$ such that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt \xi}$. If we do $x\to\infty$, then $\xi\to\infty$ also, since $\xi\in (x,x+1)$. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)=\lim_{\xi\to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt \xi}=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. You are very good at explaining!

Answer (score 1):

1. $g(x+1)-g(x)=[(x+1)-x] g'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x+1$. Divide by (x+1)-x.
2. $\frac 1  {2\sqrt {\xi}} $ is the value of $g'(\xi)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to write the Mean Value Theorem as
$$
\frac{g(y)-g(x)}{y-x}=g'(\xi)
$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. This is equivalent to the formulation you have, just by taking $h=y-x$. In this case, $y=x+1$.

The derivative of $g(x)=\sqrt x$ is $g'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt x}$, so
$$
g'(\xi)=\frac1{2\sqrt \xi}.
$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but why do we only look at the derivative of $\sqrt(x)$ and not the derivative of the full function?

Comment: It's literally the statement of the mean value theorem. In what you wrote $f$ is just a name. The MVT is applied to $g$, Which is why we wrote the answers with $g$.